# How to scale app menu bar to fit below built-in camera via Terminal

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, command-line, settings, camera

To make the menu bar for an application appear below the notch for an application, one can right-click the application, click Get Info, and check the 'Scale to fit below built-in camera' checkbox as depicted below:

[image]

Is there any way to do the same thing through the macOS Terminal application?